# Copy single postgres table from one to another instance

Tags: postgresql, psql

I a trying to copy single table from one postgres to another one, so I tried to dump the table first using

`pg_dump --host postgres1 --port 5432 --username <user> --format plain --verbose --file "batabase.backup" --table public.zones_zoneusage database`

And then tried to restore

`pg_restore --host postgres2 --port 5432 --username <user> -d database -t zones_zoneusage "batabase.backup"`

But I got following error

`pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.`

What I am missing here ?

Comment: How about leaving the `--format plain` out? It probably doesn't matter, but I would also name the result file with a sql extension. i.e. backup.sql.

Comment: copy table data in same instance or different instance

Comment: Different instance

Comment: create a link server then insert data from one instance to other

Comment: What's unclear about the hint "*Please use psql.*"?

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: You should use the psql client, not the pg_restore client. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/reference-client.html

Comment: `psql --host postgres2 --port 5432 --username <user> -d database -f batabase.backup`. If you want to use `pg_restore` the do `pg_dump ... --format=custom ...`